Switching Current Vs. Output Current - Boost Converter
I used the MIC2288YD5-TR (datasheet: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MIC2288-Data-Sheet-DS20006034C.pdf) for a project to power a MQ2 gas sensor. The input voltage was 3.7V-4.2V(lithium ion battery) and the output voltage was set to 5V via the FB resistors.
What I'm mainly confused about is the actual output of the boost converter. I know that the converter itself has a maximum switching current 1.2A, but in my case the output current would be close to 140mA since its only driving the gas sensor, LDO, MCU, and some LEDs.
Note that the picture below is from the datasheet link from above on page 6 Figure 2-1:

Looking at the efficiency graph, it seems the converter can only output 150mA with an input of 3.6V and Vout set to 12V. Does the efficiency change at a lower voltage output? Let's say I needed a circuit that requires 800mA of output current. What voltage would be required for this to be possible? How would you determine that voltage?
I am aware of the Texas Instruments Application note regarding boost converter calculations and did calculate the change in IL and the maximum switching current, but I want to know how to calculate the output current for loads higher than 500mA.


The input voltage was 3.7V-4.2V(lithium ion battery) and the output voltage was set to 5V via the FB resistors. ...  Let's say I needed a circuit that requires 800mA of output current.

800 mA output current with a 3x boost ratio means the switching current will exceed the 1 A maximum allowed for this converter IC. You'll need to find a different chip.

Looking at the efficiency graph, it seems the converter can only output 150mA with an input of 3.6V and Vout set to 12V.

The graph gives examples of use cases and the expected efficiency. It doesn't tell you every use case that is possible.

What exactly do you mean by the 3x boost ratio?
Regarding efficiency, will the boost converter have a similar trend at a lower/higher output voltage?

Your input voltage is about 4 V. Your output voltage is 12 V. 12 is about 3 times as big as 4. You are boosting the voltage by a ratio of about 3.

So in my case because the output voltage is 5V, the ratio would be 1.25, making the overall current output up to 1A given an 800mA load?

Average input current would be 1 A. Peak input current would be higher. It would also increase as the battery voltage decreases toward 3.7 V.

Would the peak input current increase due to the battery's internal resistance increasing to compensate for the decrease in voltage?

@dreece2498, yes, the duty cycle would be increased by the control circuit and this would lead to higher peak input current.
